# Joining two data frames on the closest date in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have two datasets that I would like to join based on date. One is a survey dataset, and the other is a list of prices at various dates. The dates don't match exactly, so I would like to join on the nearest date in the survey dataset (the price data is weekly).

Here's a brief snippet of what the survey dataset looks like (there are many other variables, but here's the two most relevant):

| ID | actual.date |
| --- | --- |
| 20120377 | 2012-09-26 |
| 2020455822 | 2020-11-23 |
| 20126758 | 2012-10-26 |
| 20124241 | 2012-10-25 |
| 2020426572 | 2020-11-28 |

And here's the price dataset (also much larger, but you get the idea):

| date | price.var1 | price.var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-10-30 | 2.74733926399869 | 2.73994826674735 |
| 2015-03-16 | 2.77028200438506 | 2.74079930272231 |
| 2010-10-18 | 3.4265947805337 | 3.41591263539176 |
| 2012-10-29 | 4.10095806545397 | 4.14717556976502 |
| 2012-01-09 | 3.87888859352037 | 3.93074237884497 |

What I would like to do is join the price dataset to the survey dataset, joining on the nearest date.

I've tried a number of different things, none of which have worked to my satisfaction.

```
#reading in sample data
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
survey <- fread(" ID actual.date
1:   20120377  2012-09-26
2: 2020455822  2020-11-23
3:   20126758  2012-10-26
4:   20124241  2012-10-25
5: 2020426572  2020-11-28
> ") %>% select(-V1)

price <- fread("date price.var1 price.var2
1: 2017-10-30   2.747339   2.739948
2: 2015-03-16   2.770282   2.740799
3: 2010-10-18   3.426595   3.415913
4: 2012-10-29   4.100958   4.147176
5: 2012-01-09   3.878889   3.930742") %>% select(-V1)
```

```
#using data.table

setDT(survey)[,DT_DATE := actual.date]
setDT(price)[,DT_DATE := date]

survey_price <- survey[price,on=.(DT_DATE),roll="nearest"]
#This works, and they join, but it drops a ton of observations, which won't work

#using dplyr
library(dplyr)
survey_price <- left_join(survey,price,by=c("actual.date"="date"))
#this joins them without dropping observations, but all of the price variables become NAs
```

Comment: Is there only one observation per week? If so we can merge by week.

Comment: The price dataset has one observation per week, the survey dataset does not. What I’d like to do is merge the survey dataset on the closest week date in the price dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there.
In the `DT[i,on]` syntax, `i` should be `survey` to join on all its rows

```
setDT(survey)
setDT(price)
survey_price <- price[survey,on=.(date=actual.date),roll="nearest"]
survey_price

         date price.var1 price.var2         ID
       <IDat>      <num>      <num>      <int>
1: 2012-09-26   4.100958   4.147176   20120377
2: 2020-11-23   2.747339   2.739948 2020455822
3: 2012-10-26   4.100958   4.147176   20126758
4: 2012-10-25   4.100958   4.147176   20124241
5: 2020-11-28   2.747339   2.739948 2020426572
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the dates to numeric and find the closest date from the survey for price with `Closest()` from `DescTools`, and take that value.

Example datasets

```
survey <- tibble(
  ID = sample(20000:40000, 9, replace = TRUE),
  actual.date = seq(today() %m+% days(5), today() %m+% days(5) %m+% months(2),
                    "week")
)

price <- tibble(
  date = seq(today(), today() %m+% months(2), by = "week"),
  price_1 = sample(2:6, 9, replace = TRUE),
  price_2 = sample(2:6, 9, replace = TRUE)
)
```

survey

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
     ID actual.date
  <int> <date>     
1 34592 2022-05-07 
2 37846 2022-05-14 
3 22715 2022-05-21 
4 22510 2022-05-28 
5 30143 2022-06-04 
6 34348 2022-06-11 
7 21538 2022-06-18 
8 39802 2022-06-25 
9 36493 2022-07-02
```

price

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  date       price_1 price_2
  <date>       <int>   <int>
1 2022-05-02       6       6
2 2022-05-09       3       2
3 2022-05-16       6       4
4 2022-05-23       6       2
5 2022-05-30       2       6
6 2022-06-06       2       4
7 2022-06-13       2       2
8 2022-06-20       3       5
9 2022-06-27       5       6
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate) 
library(DescTools) 

price <- price %>% 
  mutate(date = Closest(survey$actual.date %>%
                          as.numeric, date %>%
                          as.numeric) %>%
           as_date())

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  date       price_1 price_2
  <date>       <int>   <int>
1 2022-05-07       6       6
2 2022-05-14       3       2
3 2022-05-21       6       4
4 2022-05-28       6       2
5 2022-06-04       2       6
6 2022-06-11       2       4
7 2022-06-18       2       2
8 2022-06-25       3       5
9 2022-07-02       5       6

merge(survey, price, by.x = "actual.date", by.y = "date")

 actual.date    ID price_1 price_2
1  2022-05-07 34592       6       6
2  2022-05-14 37846       3       2
3  2022-05-21 22715       6       4
4  2022-05-28 22510       6       2
5  2022-06-04 30143       2       6
6  2022-06-11 34348       2       4
7  2022-06-18 21538       2       2
8  2022-06-25 39802       3       5
9  2022-07-02 36493       5       6
```